# Display playlist by album instead of by song on iPhone

Tags: itunes

I have an iPhone 5S. I want to see my playlist by albums instead of by songs. When I add an album of songs to the playlist, it shows all the songs. I can do it on iTunes on the computer but it doesn't seem to allow you to show playlist by album instead of by song.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this on your iPhone, but on a mac when you select the playlist you can go to the top right corner and change it from songs to albums for them to be sorted by album.

Answer (score -1):

This option needs to be added on the iPhone.

I like sorting through the music on my phone in Album view and its a big hassle when I have 800+ single songs in my "Gym" Playlist that get lumped in with the full albums I have on the phone.

This has led me to make a separate playlist for the full albums...but you can't view them in any other way except as a list of SONGS in the playlist....its like..damn you can't win.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! 
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.